# HTTP Get MissingRequiredQueryParameter

Tags: get, http-status-code-400, azure-batch

I am attempting to retrieve a file I have stored within a node within an Azure Batch pool. Passing a GET request using the URL:

https://ResourceName.southcentralus.batch.azure.com/jobs/adfv2-ResourceName/tasks/adaa9831-fca7-4562-8a7b-8aed60de151f/files/wd/filename.dat

Returns the error:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"https://ResourceName.southcentralus.batch.azure.com/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Batch.Protocol.Entities.Container.errors/@Element","code":"MissingRequiredQueryParameter","message":{
    "lang":"en-US","value":"A query parameter that's mandatory for this request is not specified.\nRequestId:f72f00f7-1549-4dc4-b374-abaf3bd30b58\nTime:2018-05-18T13:59:17.0275742Z"
  },"values":[
    {
      "key":"QueryParameterName","value":"api-version"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, there is no indication as to the parameter to pass...
How can I retrieve the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error response shows you what is needed in the request:

```
"values":[
  {
    "key":"QueryParameterName","value":"api-version"
  }
]
```

An `api-version` is required on all requests. So for your example, try issuing a GET using:

```
https://ResourceName.southcentralus.batch.azure.com/jobs/adfv2-ResourceName/tasks/adaa9831-fca7-4562-8a7b-8aed60de151f/files/wd/filename.dat?api-version=2018-03-01.6.1
```

You can see the full REST API documentation [for this action](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/file/getfromtask), which gives you an example.

For more information on available versions, see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/batch-service-rest-api-versioning).

Comment: Thank you, it would appear the same issue for the Authorization header: `"values": [
{
"key": "HeaderName",
"value": "Authorization"
}
]`, I rarely use HTTP requests. Where would this doc be?

Comment: You will need to construct the [proper authentication header](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/authenticate-requests-to-the-azure-batch-service). The alternative is to use an [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/) instead which is available in many languages and takes care of things like service versioning and authentication. You can also retrieve files via the UI in the Portal or using BatchLabs.

Comment: I will be calling to retrieve files from a Datafactory pipeline.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how to authorize through Azure AD?

Comment: You'll need to follow the general [ARM REST guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/azure/) and substitute the proper endpoints as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/authenticate-requests-to-the-azure-batch-service#authentication-via-azure-ad). General info about Batch AAD Auth can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth).

Comment: I am sorry, but I find this to be very confusing and the documentation goes in circles. I have no background in authentication/authorization in any way. Is there a straightforward way to simply build the Authorization header credential for the ability to access a file within a batch service node? Do I need to create a separate question?